# Spring Security to continue firing the same request after authentication

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-security

When a user clicks a button, an Ajax post request is fired an if he is not logged in a login  dialog box opens which is handled with spring security. Now when the user logs in, I want to fire the same Ajax post request. How do I achieve this? In Ajax post request, I have both headers and request body.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The login box you mentioned, is that the default login page of your application? Or do you have a custom filter / javascript that is showing the login dialog? re-running the originally request will depend on the custom filter.

Comment: Its not a page,its just a dialog box,it opens up when a user tries to access a service when they are not authenticated.

Comment: hi did you solve the problem?

Comment: I did not exactly, but I found another way which solved my problem. I created a class implementing a AuthenticationSucessHandler, which is called just after the authentication. After authentication I just reload the page. So to fire again the same request, I had to again click the button.